# glBufferSubData not working in GLSurfaceView.Renderer.onDrawFrame

Tags: android, opengl-es, glsurfaceview

I use `GLSurfaceView` to draw three points in native code, it worked great until I tried changed the point's position in `GLSurfaceView.Renderer.onDrawFrame` method.

Instead of changing the position of the point, `glBufferSubData` method caused the point to
be lost, the `glMapBufferRange` causes the same problem.

The render class of my `GLSurfaceView` code:

```
private static class Renderer implements GLSurfaceView.Renderer {

    private final GLSurfaceView glSurfaceView;

    private Renderer(GLSurfaceView glSurfaceView) {
        this.glSurfaceView = glSurfaceView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onSurfaceCreated(GL10 gl, EGLConfig config) {
        NativeMethod.nSurfaceCreated(glSurfaceView.getContext().getAssets());
    }

    @Override
    public void onSurfaceChanged(GL10 gl, int width, int height) {
        NativeMethod.nSurfaceChanged(width, height);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDrawFrame(GL10 gl) {
        NativeMethod.nDrawFrame();
    }
}
```

And in native code:

```
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL
Java_xxx_NativeMethod_nSurfaceCreated(JNIEnv *env, jclass clazz, jobject asset_manager) {
    renderer = create_program_from_assets(env, asset_manager, "vertex_shader.glsl", "fragment_shader.glsl");

    glUseProgram(renderer);
    glClearColor(1.0F, 1.0F, 1.0F, 1.0F);

    glGenVertexArrays(1, vao);
    glBindVertexArray(vao[0]);

    glGenBuffers(1, vbo);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vao[0]);
    float vertices[] = {
            -0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f,
            0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f,
            0.0f, 0.5f, 0.0f
    };
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(vertices), vertices, GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW);

    glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(float) * 3, (void *) 0);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
}

JNIEXPORT void JNICALL
Java_xxx_NativeMethod_nSurfaceChanged(JNIEnv *env, jclass clazz, jint width, jint height) {
    glViewport(0, 0, width, height);
}

JNIEXPORT void JNICALL
Java_xxx_NativeMethod_nDrawFrame(JNIEnv *env, jclass clazz) {
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    glDrawArrays(GL_POINTS, 0, 3);
}
```

The code is simple and works well. It can display three points on the screen:

[image: three points on the screen]

But when I changed the point's position using `glBufferSubData`, the point will be lost:

```
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL
Java_xxx_NativeMethod_nDrawFrame(JNIEnv *env, jclass clazz) {
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    float vertex_fr[] = {0.0F, 0.0F, 10.0F};
    glBufferSubData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0 , sizeof(vertex_fr), vertex_fr);
    glDrawArrays(GL_POINTS, 0, 3);
}
```

As you can see, the first point should be placed in the center of screen, But what happened is that the first point is missing:

[image: only two points left]
I have tried some code, I found that if I tried to changed a point, the point will be lost,
and this problem alse happened with `glMapBufferRange`.

Is the buffer cannot be changed in `GLSurfaceView.Renderer.onDrawFrame`? or is there some wrong with my code?

thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not set a projection matrix, so the near plane is 1 and the far plane is -1. The Z coordinate must be between the near and far planes, otherwise the geometry will be clipped. Change. the Z coordinate:

<s>`float vertex_fr[] = {0.0F, 0.0F, 10.0F};`</s>

```java
float vertex_fr[] = {0.0f, 0.0f, 0.5f};
```